# Aligning nodes in different tikzpictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, align, overlays, baseline

It is possible to align the baseline of two nodes in different tikzpictures. I have a tikz in an `align` environment as in the following example code

```
\begin{align}
&\tikz[remember picture]{\node(I){};} \to \Delta r \leq \frac{r}{n-1}\\
&\to\Delta r - \frac{r}{n-2} \leq 0
\end{align}
```

and another tikz after this as the following one

```
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\node at(I){$\Delta r \to \frac{r}{n-1}$};}
```

How can I make the baseline of the two nodes aligned without messing up the alignment in the `align` environment?

**Edit 1:** Minimal (not) working example

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{align*}
&\tikz[remember picture]{\node(I){};} \to \Delta r \leq \frac{r}{n-1}\\
&\to\Delta r - \frac{r}{n-2} \leq 0
\end{align*}
\visible<2->{\tikz[overlay, remember picture]{\node[anchor=east] at(I.west){$\Delta r \to \frac{r}{n-1}$};}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

In this example, the arrows are not aligned both vertically and horizontally.

The desired output:
[image]

Comment: A complete and compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) as well as a sketch of the expected output would be really useful here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vertical alignment problem is because your Ti*k*Z node, although void, has a size different from zero. The second one can be solved by the `base` anchors.

Anyway, you should look at the `tikzmark` library.

```latex
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{align*}
&\tikz[remember picture]{\node[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt](I){};} \to\Delta r \leq \frac{r}{n-1}\\
&\to\Delta r - \frac{r}{n-2} \leq 0
\end{align*}
\visible<2->{\tikz[overlay, remember picture]{\node[anchor=base east] at(I.base){$\Delta r \to \frac{r}{n-1}$};}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Still is not perfect though --- some extra space is added by `tikz`. Better using `overlay`:

```latex
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{align*}
&\tikz[remember picture, overlay]{\node(I){};}\to\Delta r \leq \frac{r}{n-1}\\
&\to\Delta r - \frac{r}{n-2} \leq 0
\end{align*}
\visible<2->{\tikz[overlay, remember picture]{\node[anchor=base east] at(I.base){$\Delta r \to \frac{r}{n-1}$};}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I knew about the `tikzmark` library, but I was hoping for a handmade solution. @Rmano I was about to point out about the white space, but this works perfectly. Thank you.